# Jenkins groovy - Traversing the failed object tree

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

Some jobs are dependant on other jobs. means that a current job will fail if one of the jobs its depend on has failed.
using build.getLog(400), printing every line, I get something like this:

```
...
Finished Build : #2875 of Job : <job1> with status : SUCCESS
Starting build job <job2>.
Returning node parameter for Linux_lean4s
Finished Build : #570 of Job : <job2> with status : SUCCESS
Starting build job <job3>.
Returning node parameter for Linux_lean4s
Finished Build : #682 of Job : <job3> with status : SUCCESS
Starting build job <job4>.
Finished Build : #214 of Job : <job4> with status : FAILURE
...
```

which means thats this job depend on job1-4, and job 4 has failed, so this job will fail too.
maybe even job4 was failed because it depended on a failed job itself.
so basically, it's possible that we have a chain of failed jobs. the first that failed caused the second that depended on the first to fail too, causing the third to fail and so on.

I wan't to traverse this chain, going all the way up to the first job that failed.

I checked the hudson jenkinis api -> [AbstractBuild](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html) and found this function:

```
public Map<AbstractProject,Fingerprint.RangeSet> getDownstreamBuilds()
```

but the line below is true:

```
build.getDownstreamBuilds().keySet().isEmpty()
```

So i didn't get anything from getDownstreamBuilds, and I didn't find other function that could help me achieve what i need.

so what function do I need to use instead?
Thanks.